# Sticky element doesn't work well with scale

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div element which is set to 'sticky' to top of its parent div. The parent div is inside a div which is scaled. While everything works as expected if scale is set to 1, the sticky element doesn't stick if the scale is set to non 1 values, such as 1.5 or 0.5.

Please see the code here:

```css
.scale {
  height: unset;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transform-origin: left top;
  width: calc(66.6667%);
}

.container {
  height: 1200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='scale'>
      <div class='container'>
        <div class='sticky'>
          I should stick to top
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>Other parts needed to scale</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If we set scale to 1.5 (transform: scale(1.5)), the sticky element is moving to the bottom as I scroll the page. If I set scale to 0.5, it will just scroll off the screen. If it's set to 1, everything works fine.

I am wondering how to keep both the 'sticky' and 'scale' working in this scenario. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're scaling the parent div, if you use 1 as a scale then the sticky div will move by 1:1 ratio

1.5 as scale will be 1.5:1 ratio so when you scroll by 100px, the sticky div will move 150px, making it go down

0.5 as scale will be 0.5:1 so it so it will move by 50px if you scroll down 100px, making it look like it's moving up

Comment: Ah I think you right, thanks for the enlightenment! So, does this mean that one possible solution would be scaling each child div, instead of the parent div?

Comment: Using transform scale will apply to everything
So don't use transform, you can just change the width height and font size

Comment: That's also a possible and better solution for that